# Why is my crontab not working properly in EC2 instance PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I want to run cron script daily at 10:12 pm. But it is running at some other time and not as per schedule.

- Default time zone already set in IST
- Also the script is working properly

See the below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What time is it running?

Comment: Right now its 10:30 PM IST and it should run at 10:12 PM, but it hasn't.

Comment: Current server time : Thu Aug  5 22:33:45 IST 2021

Comment: Check the logs to see if and when it is actually running.

Comment: Also, I just have to ask, is it possibly _finishing_ at 10:30 because this a long-running script?

Comment: The CRON hasn't run yet. Its 11:30 PM here.

Comment: What is the output of the `date` command? Is `crond` running? If you change the schedule to something more often like `* * * * *` does the script run?

Comment: - Yes if I change it to * * * * * it is running in every mint.
- Date command output - Thu Aug  5 23:46:36 IST 2021
- crond Status : Running

Comment: Did you set to 22:12 a few seconds after it became 22:12?

Comment: I wonder whether cron might be running off UTC, rather than the timezone you are personally using?

Comment: Today, Cron script run at 2021-08-06 05:04:01 AM

Comment: Time zone configured - Asia/Kolkata

Comment: Why does cron run at 05:04 AM?

Comment: You guys are degreasing my reputation which is fine but you should clear my query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: 
One thing I noticed is that the time in my log files is different then the time the 'date' command displays.

So If you change the timezone after crond has loaded, it will continue to be stuck in the previous timezone. Simply restart/reload crond, and it will pick up this change or try to restart syslog service.

Thanks